# How do I use stackshot to debug my application?

Tags: debugging, macos

I've recently been told about a useful debugging tool on Mac OS X called `stackshot`, however I don't know how to invoke it. My understanding from [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stackshot.1.html) is that it runs as a daemon, but the man page also reads as if it can be invoked from the command line. How would I go about leveraging stackshot for my currently-running application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo /usr/libexec/stackshot -i
```

Stackshot is intended for debugging system-wide issues (deadlocks etc), not single applications; as such it creates a stack dump of the entire system, not a single application.

With the default configuration, this will create a stack shot in `/Library/Logs/stackshot.log`

Comment: Thanks; I discovered if you add `-p pid` to the command line you can stackshoot (sic) a single application to check for deadlocks therein.

Comment: There's no `stackshot` in my `/usr/libexec`. I'm on 10.11.3

Answer (score 2):

Apple has asked me to produce a Stackshot on my iOS device.  To do so, when the issue occurs, simultaneously hold down and release the Home and a volume button.

Then, synch your device with iTunes.

After synching, your stackshot log file will be stored on the computer.  I don't know where it is in Windows, but on a Mac it is in:

~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice//stacks-yyyy-mm-dd-xxxxxx.log

Answer (score 0):

stackshot no longer appears to be included with OS X, at least not in 10.11. However you can still take a sample of your app using the /usr/bin/sample tool.

This is also accessible using Activity monitor:

1. Open Activity Monitor
2. Double click your app
3. Click the Sample button in the bottom left corner

That will allow you to see what is currently happening in your app so that you can debug CPU usage issues without running the app from Xcode.

Comment: the output of the activity monitor looks really strange. Can I just get a stacktrace somehow?